# gluLookAt Not Working?

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine

Why isn't gluLookAt working?

It makes no difference to the scene as if it's not even being called.

Is it because I'm using `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` if I don't include it I get nothing on screen.

I'm using GLFW, GLEW, and GLM.

```
// game.cpp:
Car* car;
void Game::init()
{
    //  LOADING SHADERS:
    loadShaders();

    //  CREATING ENTITIES:
    car = new Car();
    //cube->position.x = -0;
    car->position.z = -2;
    entities.push_back(car);

    //  INITIAL GL PARAMETERS:
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);                         //  BACK FACE CULLING
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                        //  DRAW NON-OBSCURED
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);      //  FILL POLYGON MODE

    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 0.0f);           //  BACKGROUND COLOR

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(CAMERA_FOVY, (GLdouble)WINDOW_WIDTH / (GLdouble)WINDOW_HEIGHT, CAMERA_ZNEAR, CAMERA_ZFAR);
}

void Game::update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != entities.size(); ++i)
    {
        entities[i]->update();
    }
}

void Game::render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, car->position.x, car->position.y, car->position.z, 0, -1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i != entities.size(); ++i)
    {
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(entities[i]->position.x, entities[i]->position.y, entities[i]->position.z);
        glRotatef(entities[i]->rotation.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(entities[i]->rotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(entities[i]->rotation.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        entities[i]->render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your shaders?

Comment: Considering the use of `gluLookAt (...)` I am going to take a wild guess and say that this code is completely fixed-function ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `glLoadIdentity` at the beginning of each iteration of the entity for loop. On the first iteration this will replace the matrix that was set by `gluLookAt`.

To ensure this view matrix applies to all your entities you want to call `glPushMatrix` after the call to `gluLookAt`. Make sure to balance this with a call to `glPopMatrix` after your for loop.